Jetpack Compose last element in row not displaying
I have the following chat view, however the last element in the Row (the KeyboardArrowRight icon) isn't displaying.  For the life of me I can't figure out why. Any fresh eyes on this would be appreciated!
If I apply a fixed width modifier to the the middle element (the middle column with the profile name, sent time, last message and unread message circle indicator), the KeyboardArrowRight icon displays, but clearly don't want to do this because it won't look great on different width screens
@Composable
fun ChatView() {

    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp
    val chatIsNew = true

    val chats = 4
    
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(1),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(30.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
    ) {

        items(chats) { chat ->

            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .border(
                        width = 1.dp,
                        color = Color.Black,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
                    )
                    .padding(10.dp)
            ) {

                //Profile image
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(
                            screenWidth / 4.25F,
                            screenWidth / 4.25F
                        )
                        .background(
                            color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.1F),
                            shape = CircleShape
                        )
                ) {
                }



                Column(
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
                ) {

                    Row(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {

                        //Profile Name
                        Text(
                            text = "Profile Name",
                            style = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 18.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                                color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                                    Color.White
                                } else {
                                    Color.Black
                                },
                            ),
                            maxLines = 1
                        )


                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))


                        //Sent time
                        Text(
                            text = "10:00",
                            style = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                                color = Color.Gray,
                            )
                        )
                    }


                    Row(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        //Last message
                        Text(
                            text = "Last message to go here",
                            style = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                                color = Color.Gray,
                            ),
                            maxLines = 2,
                            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        )


                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))


                        //New chat and unread message circle indicator
                        if (chatIsNew == true) {

                            Box(
                                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(12.dp)
                                    .background(
                                        color = Color.Blue.copy(alpha = 0.75F),
                                        shape = CircleShape
                                    )
                            ) {
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }



                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Rounded.KeyboardArrowRight,
                    contentDescription = "null",
                    tint = Color.Gray,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp)
                )


            }

        }
    }

}


This is the best minimal reproducible example code I have ever seen on a question in stackoverflow. I just copy-pasted, added imports, and the problem is immediately reproducable. I upvoted!

Jetpack Compose measures Composable children in the order they appear. As you have not specified any width Modifiers for the children of the topmost Row, each child will implicitly use wrapContentWidth(). Jetpack Compose will then give each child the screen space it requests, which in this case pushes the last Icon Composable off screen.
You can solve this by applying the weight Modifier on the middle Column like this:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
) {
    //...
}

The weighted Composable is measured after all unweighted children are measured. As a result, all unweighted children will take the width they need, and the Column takes the remaining width. This ensures that nothing gets pushed off screen.
Output:


Awesome.  Explanation much appreciated too.  Thanks!
